# Merge two String objects in java with Jackson output

Tags: java, jackson

I want to concatenate multiple Jackson objects. I have two String object like this

```
{'Key1' : 'Value1' , 'Key2' : 'Value2'}
```

and this

```
{'Key3' : 'Value3' , 'Key4' : 'Value4'}
```

result must be

```
{'Key1' : 'Value1' , 'Key2' : 'Value2' , 'Key3' : 'Value3' , 'Key4' : 'Value4'}
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: The question seems to request a solution with Jackson. None of the answers in the possible duplicate offers a solution with Jackson specifically,

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved with Jackson by parsing each `String` into `ObjectNode` (basically tree representation of the JSON) and concatenating with the `setAll` method. Something like this:

```
String json1 = "{\"Key1\": \"Value1\", \"Key2\": \"Value2\"}";
String json2 = "{\"Key3\": \"Value3\", \"Key4\": \"Value4\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode node1 = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(json1);
ObjectNode node2 = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(json2);

JsonNode merged = node1.setAll(node2);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(merged));
```

Documentation [ObjectNode::setAll](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#setAll-java.util.Map-)